# How to Reduce import from react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, import, jsx

I'm trying to reduce the amount of imports in my react files, I how do I group the imports so I  can use the { } to get more then one from a file.

```
  // assets
  import location from "../../assets/home/header/location.svg";
  import banner from "../../assets/home/header/banner.jpg";
  import delivery from "../../assets/home/section-a/delivery.svg";
  import arrow from "../../assets/home/section-b/arrow.svg";
  import stock1 from "../../assets/home/section-c/stock-1.jpg";
  import stock2 from "../../assets/home/section-c/stock-2.jpg";
  import stock3 from "../../assets/home/section-c/stock-3.jpg";

  // components
  import IconList from "./IconList";
  import Image from "../../components/Image";
  import DisplayCard from "../../components/CardGroup/DisplayCard";
  import ListDetail from "../../components/CardGroup/ListDetail";
  import Slide from "../../components/Slide/index";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images, SVG and those kind of files you cannot use `named export` the only way is to

**import them one by one**

You can use `named export {}` for example for multiple `functions` or `variables` in same file.

```
export const example = () => () ;
```

so you can after

import them like :

```
import {example, example2,example3} from "./examples";
```

or using the `*` to import all the export `functions` or `variables`

```
 import * as Foo  from "./examples";

 const x = Foo.example();
```

Comment: Can you explain how would one use `*`?